# Unable to install any extension through magento connect manager

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, cpanel

I have a fresh installation of magento 1.9.2 on my live server and i want to install few extenstions but when i try to install it gives me following error:

Checking dependencies of packages
Installing package community/magento_absolute_theme_free 2.0.0

> CONNECT ERROR: Failed to create directory:
>   /home/softwar252/public_html/magento/./app/code/community/TM/Core/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Grid/Renderer
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   /home/software252/public_html/magento/./skin/frontend/f001/yellow/images
>   /home/software252/public_html/magento/./skin/frontend/f001/yellow/images
>   Check permissions

any leads on this would be helpful. thank you in advance.

Comment: REad this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86367/cant-install-uninstall-extensions-using-mcm It's possible a permission problems. What it's your APache+PHP model? mod_php, php-fpm, fastcgi,...?  Link speak about one model, others model possible other solution. But i think a problem with permission

Comment: ok. now how would I obtain  'APache+PHP model' details and also enlighten me more on what needs to be done to sort out file permission issue. @abkrim

Comment: Usually your sysadmin. If you are root you must to be know this. ps aux|grep http, try ps aux|grep apache. And ps aux|grep php. That show your apache user and if php it's on model cgi or similar. Also show user and group for ls -lisa /home/softwar252/public_html |grep magento

Comment: Problem with the permission of your magento directories  find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Comment: @abkrim   I do not have root access to the terminal of the server to try those commands.

Comment: You can use FTP for se permission instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing new extension to live site may cause many problems, in your case i think directory is already exist. to Download extension use can you http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php from here you can directly download any extension just enter extension key in text field and download thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If the following files exist try removing (or renaming if you prefer to be safer) them.

```
downloader/connect.cfg
downloader/cache.cfg
```

These are generated by Magento the first time you use connect. The cache file stores a full path to your install, so when you move to a new server this likely isn't a valid path.

You might want to try to do a manual install:

Convert your magento connect 2.0 to a direct download: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php
Open your FTP client and upload the extension in your Magento folder
No files should be overwritten,

Flush magento cache and then log out and back into magento backend

Go to configuration > advanced to check if module is listed and enabled

Please refer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24120/unable-to-install-any-extension-using-magento-connect-manager-no-answer

Comment: "I have a fresh installation of magento 1.9.2 on my live server and i want to install few extenstions but when i try to install it gives me following error:" if **fresh installation** your solution it's not correct

Comment: @Sajan Saj Where should I upload the theme extension in magento folder?